# Reference module with multiple resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraspace

I am trying to create an AWS route53 hosted zone and add records to it. I added the following resources to a module `main.tf`

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name = var.name
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "zone_data" {
  name = var.name

}

resource "aws_route53_record" "record" {
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.zone_data.zone_id
  name    = var.record_name
  type    = var.record_type
  ttl     = var.record_ttl
  records = var.record_value
}
```

Then I reference that module in a stack `main.py` as follows:

```
module "route53" {
  source = "../../modules/route53"
  name   = "website.com"
  type   = "NS"
  ttl    = "30"

}
```

My issue is that building the stack will use the same name variable for both `zone` and `record` resources. How do I add another name to the stack module `route53` for the `record` resource that is different from the `zone` resource?

Comment: What is the point of the data source here? What are you actually trying to create here? Like the end product?

Comment: You should never have a `resource` and `data` that point to the same thing. Everything on `data.aws_route53_zone.zone_data` is also available via the resource `aws_route53_zone.zone`. The first time you run this, before the zone is created, the data source will actually throw an error because it is evaluated before the resource is created.

Comment: @theherk I used the data source to access the zone id when creating the records for the zone.  The end product is creating a hosted zone on AWS Route53 and assigning Records to it.

Comment: @mallet: Does the zone already exist outside this state or not? If sone, use the data source. If not, use the resource. But not both.

Comment: @MarkB and theherk, got you. The zone actually exists; hence I haven't received any error as you mentioned. Probably it is more appropriate to access the zone id from the resource directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do in the module is create a zone and a record, you could use [split](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/split) to get the zone from the record name given. Like this:

#### main.tf

```
module "route53" {
  source = "./modules/route53"
  name   = "something.website.com"
  type   = "NS"
  ttl    = "30"
}
```

#### modules/route53/main.tf

```
variable "name" {}
variable "type" {}
variable "ttl" {}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  name = split(".", var.name)[0]
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.this.zone_id
  name    = var.name
  type    = var.type
  ttl     = var.ttl
  records = [var.name]
}
```

If however, you want multiple records in that zone, you could consider something like this, but this will depend heavily on what record configuration you're after.

#### main.tf

```
module "route53" {
  source = "./modules/route53"
  name   = "website.com"

  record_configs = {
    something = {
      type    = "A"
      records = ["192.168.0.99"]
    }
    other = {
      type    = "CNAME"
      records = ["something.website.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

#### modules/route53/main.tf

```
variable "name" {}
variable "record_configs" {}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "this" {
  name = var.name
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  for_each = var.record_configs

  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.this.zone_id
  name    = each.key
  type    = each.value.type
  records = each.value.records
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple records and names, the best way is to use `for_each`. For example:

```
variable "names" {
    default = ["website.com", "website1.com", "website2.com"]
}
```

then

```
module "route53" {
  source = "../../modules/route53"
  for_each = toset(var.name)
  name   = each.key
  type   = "NS"
  ttl    = "30"

}
```

This way you can have same module for multiple names.

Comment: I can see this work for creating multiple zones using. the `zone` resource but won't affect the `record` zone as required.

Answer (score 0):

Randomly experimenting with solutions got me to add the resource variables' names as arguments to the module. This seems to allow referring to arguments of a specific resource in the root module if its argument name is the same as other resources (e.g. `record_name` vs `name`).

```
module "route53" {
  source = "../../modules/route53"
  name   = "website.com"
  record_name   = "_auth.website.com"
  record_type   = "NS"
  record_ttl    = "30"

}
```